# Accessing product and category information from a custom PHP script in Magento

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

What I'm trying to do is gain access to all of my product and category information in a particular store from a custom PHP script in Magento. I have already included Mage.php, and can access the store info, but I'm not sure how to proceed from here

```
 <?php 
 include '../../../../app/Mage.php';

 $allStores = Mage::app()->getStore(6);

 var_dump($allStores);
  ?>
```

This gives me access to the store information, but if i try to call ->getProduct() it throws an error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are most likely looking for a product collection, which is a Magento data structure that contains a grouping of products:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();
$collection->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$collection->addStoreFilter(8);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($product->getData());
}

$categories = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->getCollection();

foreach ($categories as $category) {
    Zend_Debug::dump($category)
}
```

The product object in Magento is fairly complex, given Magento's EAV data structure.